# Allowing normal user to mount and eject devices

Tags: debian, mount, polkit, pcmanfm

In the file manager PCManFM I can access discs in my USB DVD drive but I cannot eject them or access other USB storage devices - I get the error message "Not Authorized". Any clues?

I use Debian 7.7.0 and my window manager is launched by .xinitrc with

```
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session blackbox
```

Comment: This is usually an issue related to permissions of the specific block device. You might not have the necessary permissions to access the relevant device. Are you a member of the relevant group, probably cdrom or dvd or similar?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't think the problem is specific to a device; so far I have tried with an MP3 player, a digital camera and a tablet. I can't access any of them without being root. As far as I understand the relevant group is `plugdev` and I am a member of it.

Comment: Ah, I assume these are all mounted as mass storage devices, is that right? What does the `mount` command show for the relevant mounted device? Also, how are you mounting them? Maybe you just need to modify your mount permissions.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Well, the problem is that I can't mount the devices in PCManFM. They show up but I can't access them.

Comment: Do you have `udisks2` installed ?

Comment: Forget PCManFM. Use the command line.

Comment: @Costas No, I have udisks version 1.0.4-7wheezy1 installed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha If I want to look through some images on my digital camera say, the command line is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: In opposite of `mount` cli there are 3 possible way to settle problem: 1) install `udisks2` 2) change the `udev` riles 3) add to `/etc/fstab` lines for external disks whith option `uid=$(id -u)`

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom if you want to figure out why you have access problems, you want the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the window manager in a ConsoleKit session:

```
exec ck-launch-session blackbox
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Create a file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`, for instance called `udisks.pkla`, with the following content:

```
[Allow normal users to access removable media]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=yes
```